# Convergence of measures of sets with measure zero boundary

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $P_k$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, and $P$ be probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the sigma-algebra of Borel sets and suppose that $P_k\longrightarrow P$ weakly.

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be open or closed with $P(\partial A)=0$, though not necessarily with $P_k(\partial A)=0$, where $\partial A$ denotes the boundary wrt. standard topology.

Must we have that $P_k(A)\longrightarrow P(A)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is a consequence of the Portmanteau theorem (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures)). It's not even necessary for $A$ to be open or closed; it's enough for $A$ to be a Borel set (as long as $\mathbb{P}(\partial A)=0$).